# How ASP.NET will render Hidden field and a textbox with visibility property as false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Visible = "false"></asp:TextBox>
```

How ASP.Net will render `asp:HiddenField` and `asp:TextBox` with visibility property as false?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context of you html

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Visible = "false"></asp:TextBox>
```

`text-box` will not be render on the browser.
But the `hidden field` will be rendered.

The control visibility which you set from the server side code will not be render on the browser.
 You you want to use the use `css` `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

It will render both the same as

```
<input id="_controlId" type="hidden" value="" name="_controlId">
```

You can open your page in browser and look at page source.

If you want server not to render your controls at all put them into `PlaceHolder` and set property `Visible = "false"`

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible = "false">
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out yourself.  Run your .aspx page and click View Source on the page.

The hidden field will be included in the markup, but you won't be able to visually see it on the page.

The TextBox is set as invisible from the server side.  It won't turn up at all unless you change the Visible property to true.

Answer (score 0):

The term "render" refers to ASP.NET's act of creating the HTML for the .aspx Page,When you set Visible = false to a control, it is not rendered.  That means there is no HTML representation of that control sent to the page.  Set the style only.

You can set the style as display: none from server side code like this:

```
FromDate.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none")
```

This way the element is still there for JavaScript to manipulate.